# Neural net package in R

Tags: r

Which package in R  contain recursive neural network and auto associative neural network functions?

I am using `nnet` and `neuralnet` function but need to use recursive neural network or auto associative neural net.

Comment: Try:  `library(sos; ???neural`
That's often the fastest way to find existing functions.

Answer (score 5):

Googling for `R neural networks` gave a lot of useful links. The [nnet](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nnet/index.html) package seems a much used way of using neural networks in R. It is included standardly in R. Googling for `CRAN neural networks` gave more interesting links: [neuralnet](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/neuralnet/index.html) and [RSNNS](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RSNNS/index.html). Maybe these links contain something to your linking.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a look at the [RWeka package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RWeka/index.html) which gives you access to the algorithms implemented in [Weka](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/). I don't know what a recursive neural net is, but if you mean *recurrent* neural net, there's a [Weka package](http://jsalatas.ictpro.gr/weka/) for that.