# Echo state network?

Tags: r, neural-network, time-series

I've heard from a couple of people recently that echo state networks are good for time series modeling.  So I figure it's worth a try.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_state_network

It's a type of recurrent network where only the weights in the output layer are learned, and the other weights are randomized.

To what extent are their libraries/package in R that could be used to create an echo state network?

(Note: there is this question: [Neural net package in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521752/neural-net-package-in-r) , which is possibly related, but it asks for 'recursive' networks, whereas I'm looking for 'recurrent' or 'echo state' networks).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I know the question is old, but this might be useful nonetheless, maybe to other people.

Here you can find a working demo [source code of a minimalistic Echo State Network in R](http://minds.jacobs-university.de/mantas/code). It's not a full-fledged library, but I hope is easy to understand and adapt to your application.

```
# A minimalistic Echo State Networks demo with Mackey-Glass (delay 17) data 
# in "plain" R.
# by Mantas Lukosevicius 2012
# http://minds.jacobs-university.de/mantas

# load the data
trainLen = 2000
testLen = 2000
initLen = 100

data = as.matrix(read.table('MackeyGlass_t17.txt'))

# plot some of it
while( dev.cur() != 1 ) dev.off() # close all previous plots
dev.new()
plot(data[1:1000],type='l')
title(main='A sample of data')

# generate the ESN reservoir
inSize = outSize = 1
resSize = 1000
a = 0.3 # leaking rate

set.seed(42)
Win = matrix(runif(resSize*(1+inSize),-0.5,0.5),resSize)
W = matrix(runif(resSize*resSize,-0.5,0.5),resSize)
# Option 1 - direct scaling (quick&dirty, reservoir-specific):
#W = W * 0.135 
# Option 2 - normalizing and setting spectral radius (correct, slow):
cat('Computing spectral radius...')
rhoW = abs(eigen(W,only.values=TRUE)$values[1])
print('done.')
W = W * 1.25 / rhoW

# allocated memory for the design (collected states) matrix
X = matrix(0,1+inSize+resSize,trainLen-initLen)
# set the corresponding target matrix directly
Yt = matrix(data[(initLen+2):(trainLen+1)],1)

# run the reservoir with the data and collect X
x = rep(0,resSize)
for (t in 1:trainLen){
    u = data[t]
    x = (1-a)*x + a*tanh( Win %*% rbind(1,u) + W %*% x )
    if (t > initLen)
        X[,t-initLen] = rbind(1,u,x)
}

# train the output
reg = 1e-8  # regularization coefficient
X_T = t(X)
Wout = Yt %*% X_T %*% solve( X %*% X_T + reg*diag(1+inSize+resSize) )

# run the trained ESN in a generative mode. no need to initialize here, 
# because x is initialized with training data and we continue from there.
Y = matrix(0,outSize,testLen)
u = data[trainLen+1]
for (t in 1:testLen){
    x = (1-a)*x + a*tanh( Win %*% rbind(1,u) + W %*% x )
    y = Wout %*% rbind(1,u,x)
    Y[,t] = y
    # generative mode:
    u = y
    ## this would be a predictive mode:
    #u = data[trainLen+t+1] 
}

# compute MSE for the first errorLen time steps
errorLen = 500
mse = ( sum( (data[(trainLen+2):(trainLen+errorLen+1)] - Y[1,1:errorLen])^2 )
    / errorLen )
print( paste( 'MSE = ', mse ) )

# plot some signals
dev.new() 
plot( data[(trainLen+1):(trainLen+testLen+1)], type='l', col='green' )
lines( c(Y), col='blue' )
title(main=expression(paste('Target and generated signals ', bold(y)(italic(n)), 
    ' starting at ', italic(n)==0 )))
legend('bottomleft',legend=c('Target signal', 'Free-running predicted signal'), 
    col=c('green','blue'), lty=1, bty='n' )

dev.new()
matplot( t(X[(1:20),(1:200)]), type='l' )
title(main=expression(paste('Some reservoir activations ', bold(x)(italic(n)))))

dev.new()
barplot( Wout )
title(main=expression(paste('Output weights ', bold(W)^{out})))
```

Comment: Ok, let's go with this, since it does provide an echo-state implementation, and it's been 2.5 years :-D

Answer (score 1):

Granted that this does not answer to your question about R, I'm almost sure you could be able to implement an ESN easily by yourself (unless you need the more advanced/esoteric features).

Have a look [at the definition of the ESN made by Jaeger](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Echo_State_Network): all you need are equations (1) and (2) for the internal state and the output, plus equation (3) or (4) for the learning. The implementation is quite straightforward and you'll be fine with nothing more than matrix multiplication, norm and pseudoinverse.

P.S. Actually "recurrent" and "recursive" neural networks are not very different things. The term "recursive" is often - but not always - referred to those neural networks that deal with graphs while the "recurrent" networks handle sequences/time series (which are a special case of graphs). Both "recurrent" and "recursive" networks have cycles in their hidden layers, so their internal status it's *recursively* defined. A part from the linguistic mess, the point is that you can try to use the existing libraries and adapt them to your needs.

Comment: Consider making a comment with a summary of the points and links you've provided as this is not, as you yourself have observed, an answer to the question asked.

Comment: I'm sorry but there is no way to turn my post into an actual answer since, as far as I know, there are no libraries for ESN in R. 

Anyway the idea behind the ESN is that you can avoid the use of those complex algorithms that you usually need for the training of recurrent networks. The main feature of an ESN is that it is very simple, so my suggestion is: exploit this simplicity and implement it by yourself. Looking for a library may be a waste of time, even more if the library is intended to provide support for recurrent networks, since the training of an ESN only involves a linear readout.

Comment: About the link, well, that page contains the definition of ESN and it is written by ESN creator, Herbert Jaeger. You couldn't find a simpler or more trustworthy description of how an ESN works. Does it really makes sense that I try to summarize it here? If you are interested in the ESN - whether you use a library or not - you should have _at least_ read that page. If you think you'll be fine with a summary made by me... well... you are wrong.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! My comment is referring to some  [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer) on how to answer questions on SO. What you've given isn't strictly an answer to the asker's question as it's been framed as a question about how to use R libraries to implement ESN, not about the nuances of defining ESN. You also end by suggesting that existing libraries by tried, something the asker is doing by asking the question.